# Issues with indexing in python

Tags: python, list, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a list A in python containing some number like [1,4 ,10]. I have another matrix consisting of 10 columns and some rows with the first column being numbers like [1 1 1  2 2 2 2 2  3 3 4 4 4 4 5 .... and so on. Now I want to retrieve those rows from this another array whose first column consists of the numbers in the list A. How can I do it in python?

Comment: What do you mean with "array" (another list, maybe)? What is a "column"? Is your "array" nested? Show some code please.

Comment: @Hyperboreus. I have updated the question. I made a mistake in the original one. I should have said matrix,

Comment: `matrix` isn't a built-in type in Python.  Are you using the `numpy` library?  Or do you simply have a list of lists, like `[[1,2],[3,4]]`?

Comment: @DSM actually it is numpy.ndarray

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
target_list = [1, 4, 10]

a = np.array([[1,0],
              [5,0],
              [10,0],
              [4,0],
              [1,0],
              [7,0]])

first_col = a[:,0]

# create a boolean array
to_retrieve = np.in1d(first_col, target_list)

result = a[to_retrieve]
```

Result:

```
>>> result # retrieved rows whose first column elements are in the target list
array([[ 1,  0],
       [10,  0],
       [ 4,  0],
       [ 1,  0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a matrix as in `m[x + y * width]` then you can retrieve row `X` using a *slice*.

For example:

```
row_index = 5
column_count = 10
start = row_index * column_count
end = start + column_count
row = m[start:end]
```

And thus to do what you want

```
rows = []
for index in list_A:
    rows.append(list_A[index * 10:index * 10 + 10])
```

If you are talking about retrieving the columns then it's like this

```
columns = []
for index in list_A:
    columns.append(list_A[index:len(list_A):10])
```